# DataGridView How to change the color of a cell if the text didn't fit on the column fixed width?

Tags: vb.net

A Datagridview with fixed width. If the text of the cell did't fit on the column VB.NET automatically show a tip with the complete text for that cell. That is fine but the user only know there's more text if he moved the mouse over the cell.

I want to change the color of the background of the cell or the font when the text is greater than the column

**The only way is using DataGridViewCell.MeasureTextWidth Method or there's a more easy way?**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.measuretextwidth(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Public Shared Function MeasureTextWidth (
    graphics As Graphics,
    text As String,
    font As Font,
    maxHeight As Integer,
    flags As TextFormatFlags
) As Integer
```

With this function we can get the width of the text in pixels and then compare that value with the column width

Comment: That method will do the actual measuring - all you have to do is call it.

Comment: Thanks. I have trouble with the parameters graphics and flags. Graphics I think is System.Drawing. The datagrid use normal font, so I think the flag is must be empty. In fact I'm using the default Microsoft Sans Serif, 8,25pt

Comment: Since you want to change the backcolor anyway call it from the `CellPainting` event - the event args will have the `Graphics` object to use, the text (`FormattedValue`) and some other things you might need/want  like `AdvancedBorderStyle` or the `CellStyle`